# Combine two NIC's into one preserving routing (DMZ server / Windows or Linux)

Tags: routing, bonding, dmz, bridge, nic

We have a DMZ server with two NIC's, one is accessed from the Internet (public IP) and one from behind the internal firewall (private IP).

One application has problems to cope with a 2 IP's / 2 NIC's configuration, it only supports 2 IP's on 1 NIC.

We cannot use 1 NIC for security reasons, but what about merging those two NIC's into 1 virtual NIC inside the server itself? Would this NIC be a bonding device, a combination of bridging and routing or something else?

**In short, there are 2 IP's and 2 interfaces, but the application needs to be accessed from both networks though 1 interface.**

This is actually a Windows server, but a linux solution is also acceptable.

Comment: What stupid application cares about the network interfaces, that also happens to be cross-platform?  If you can't have multiple nics for security reasons, I doubt any kind of bridging is a good idea, since they will have security implications.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Other way around - no problem: One line, multiple IPs/VLANs whatever. Or: Serveral lines for the same VLAN.

But here you have two physically different networks. I can`t think of a way of putting them together onto one device without the risk of routing these networks.

If you really have to you could try to put two VLANs onto the same line leading to a single NIC in your server. But I doubt that the result will be usable as "single interface" for your application.